# How to execute a code after an operator has been executed?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator, panel

My problem: I need to execute a code after an operator has finished.

The operator is a **non modal** operator with the `UNDO` option to show the operator menu with its properties. I know that technically is not being executed, is executed once.

**My objective is to call that code when the undo panel dissappears** (I'm doing some gizmos drawing and I want them to stop drawing when the menu goes away). But despite the execute is called once, I want them to remain being drawn while the operator's menu is drawn.

(With undo panel, I mean the panel that is shown right after executing some operators:)

[image]

At the moment, I have a pretty bad solution I don't like a single bit:

- A timer that basically checks when the active operator has changed:

  ```
    def check_operator_has_finished_timer():

        active_operator = bpy.context.active_operator

        if active_operator is None or isinstance(active_operator, My_OT_class) == False:
            unregister_drawing_handlers() # This simply unregisters the drawing gizmos
            return None
  ```

The problem with that is:

- It continuous running after the OT's menu has gone. `unregister_drawing_handlers()` is only called when I trigger a different operator manually in the UI (basically something that overrides `bpy.context.active_operator`)

Ideas I had in mind (but not sure if they are possible and how (thats why I'm asking)):

- I thought about iterating all panels in the UI (not sure if Blender allows that), and I guess that maybe that way I could tell if the OT's undo panel is on. (and if the panels is not thre, I call my `unregister_drawing_handlers()`).

(Any different idea would be appreciated. I'm still a newbie and I don't know if maybe I'm missing a basic method that is automatically called when the OT is finished and I'm missing something trivial).

Thank you so much for reading and for any help, much appreciated :)

Comment: Hello ! AFAIK there is no way to differentiate when an operator is first called and when it is re-run due to the redo panel, nor when the redo panel is closed. You'd have to resort to hacky workarounds I'm afraid.

Comment: Hello Gorgious! Much appreciated as always friend, at least is good to know that is not possible hehe. Time to embrace a more creative approach :]